# Rails bundle install production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I'm still new to rails/ruby/bundler and am a little confused.

In our `config/application.rb` file there's this bundler segment:

```
if defined?(Bundler)         
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

and in our `Gemfile` we use different groups, e.g.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.7.0", :group => [:development, :test]
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'watchr'
  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
  gem 'spectator'                          
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'wirble'
end
```

But when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install` (or `bundle install --deployment`), it still installs gems from the development/test group...

Why does this happens or how can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

[THIS ANSWER IS OUTDATED](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/7531)

---

Take a look at `--without` option:

`bundle install --without development test`

By default Bundler installs all gems and your application uses the gems that it needs. Bundler  itself knows nothing about Rails and the current environment.

Comment: I know about `--without`, but it seems very in-elegant, particularly considering those configuration directives in `config/application.rb` (which are supposed to address exactly this) and also considering this quote: [Rails 3 comes with baked in support with bundler.](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html)

Comment: Bundle install command is totally independent from Rails. It just looks into your Gemfile, it doesn't care what libraries your application actually requires in the mentioned config. In fact, you can skip Bundler.require and require libs manually from any group. I agree, that Rails could integrate better in this case with Bundler, but it doesn't.

Comment: I see. So I guess it's fair to say that rails knows about bundler (i.e. in `config/application.rb` and also `config/boot.rb`), but bundler doesn't know anything about rails... It only reads the Gemfile and doesn't use any of those rails files. I think the coin finally dropped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: actually this seems elegant as it's excluding 'groups' in your Gemfile, not environments in your Rails app. I know this has been said but when I thought about it this way it made more sense to me.

Comment: Not sure if this is something that changed in the last four years, but arguments to `--without` are supposed to be separated with `:`s, not spaces. So I believe it should be `bundle install --without development:test`.

Comment: @JoeFreeman using version 1.12.5 both produce the line `Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.`

Comment: @JoeFreeman, wrong, as Bndler docs say: "A space-separated list of groups referencing gems to skip during installation.". So the right syntax would be just `bundle install --without=development test`, etc. See https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-install.1.html

Comment: This option is being deprecated.  See https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/7531

Comment: Apologies but I just updated your answer with a message to show the given solution is outdated.

Comment: [DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set --local without 'development test'`, and stop using this flag
`

Comment: the --without flag is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to use the [`bundle-only` ruby gem](https://github.com/MOZGIII/bundle-only). It can be used as follows:

```
> gem install bundle-only
> bundle-only production
```

This library does not pollute your bundler configs or augment `Gemfile.lock`; it is a simple alternative to the built in `bundle --without every other group` option that [`bundler`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler) provides.

Answer (score 3):

The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions.

Instead use `bundle config set --local without 'production'`

> Flags passed to bundle install or the Bundler runtime, such as --path
> foo or --without production, are remembered between commands and saved
> to your local application's configuration (normally,
> ./.bundle/config).
>
> However, this will be changed in bundler 3, so it's better not to rely
> on this behavior. If these options must be remembered, it's better to
> set them using bundle config (e.g., bundle config set --local without
> 'production').

source: https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-config.1.html#REMEMBERING-OPTIONS