# How to deploy and run bundle install using docker & ansible ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ansible, bundle, bluepill

I'm deploying ROR application using Ansible with Docker, Ruby Docker image created & pushed to the Docker HUB, Ansible cloned the Application from the Private repo to the Target Server, the docker container created successfully, but not able to run the Ruby Commands like Bundle install, DB Migrate, Rake Task. These commands need to run while deploying in Interactive mode from Ansible Code.

And how to start the application after running the above task with unicorn.

This is to Automate the Deployment process Using Ansible, previously using Capistrano but now we are migrating from Capistrano to Ansible.

```
---
- hosts: Ec2-Instance
  become: true
  tasks:
   - name: Creating Deploy path
     file:
       state: directory
       path: "/var/www/"
  - name: Copying SSH Key | Temp
    copy:
      src: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      dest: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      owner: deployer
      group: deployer
      mode: 400
  - name: Cloning a web application to the application path
    git:
      repo: private repo
      version: master
      dest: /var/www/app-path/ 
      accept_hostkey: yes
    register: git
     - name: Remove SSH Key
       shell: "sudo rm -rf ~/.ssh/id_rsa"

  - name: Run Ruby Docker Container
    docker_container:
      name: 'container_name'
      image: 'docker-hub/ruby-2.4.1:0.1'
      tty: yes
      detach: true
      restart: yes # not required. Use with started state to force a matching container to be stopped and restarted.
      interactive: yes # not required. Keep stdin open after a container is launched, even if not attached.
      state: started
      volumes: /var/www/app-path:/var/www/app-path/
      working_dir: /var/www/app-path/
      env:
        gem_path: /var/www/app-path
        gemfile: /var/www/app-path
      bundler:
        deployment_mode: production
```

I expect Ansible Playbook to deploy the Ruby on Rails application with Docker / Nginx / Unicorn

Comment: In what way does it fail?  It looks like there may be a problem with the `volumes` argument to `docker_container`, which should be a list, unless it has a special case for "someone passed a single string". There also seem to be a few indenting errors, but it's hard to tell if those are realy errors or copy-and-paste errors.

Comment: Playbook successfully created the docker container, but when try to execute the bundler task inside the docker container means its failed and the container is exited in state, and I don't have problem with volumes argument.

Comment: What sort of errors do you get from the bundler task?

Comment: Error, msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_container) module: bundler Supported parameters include: its printing the modules my code was cloned successfully and if I disable the bundler task means its able create the container without fail & its running in state.

Comment: Your ansible script is failing at "bundler:" as this is not in available parameters in docker_container module. Can you try disabling it? Is it critical here?  Check avaialble parameters here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html

Comment: okay I will remove that and how to declare the bundler task in the playbook... help me out

Comment: You can use "command:" parameter in docker_container to run any command/script inside docker. You can try mounting a shared location having the script  using "volumes:" parameter and then run that script inside docker using "command:".

Comment: If you're copying the entire application source tree anyways, and running `bundle install` on the target system, why not do _everything_ in Ansible (including installing Ruby on the target host) and skip Docker?

Answer (score 0):

You playbook is failing because you have specified below parameter which is not a valid parameter in docker_container module ([docker_container module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html)

```
...
bundler:
      deployment_mode: production
```

An alternative approach here could be like this

create a shell script in /var/www/app-path/install-ror.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

working_dir=/var/www/app-path/
cd $working_dir

export gem_path=/var/www/app-path
export gemfile=/var/www/app-path

#see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912614/rails-bundle-install-production-only 
gem install bundle-only

#install only production modules
bundle-only production
```

Update your playbook as follows

```
- name: Run Ruby Docker Container
    docker_container:
        name: 'container_name'
        image: 'docker-hub/ruby-2.4.1:0.1'
        tty: yes
        detach: true
        restart: yes # not required. Use with started state to force a matching container to be stopped and restarted.
        interactive: yes # not required. Keep stdin open after a container is launched, even if not attached.
        state: started
        volumes: /var/www/app-path:/var/www/app-path/
        working_dir: /var/www/app-path/
        command: /var/www/app-path/install-ror.sh
```

You can follow the output to improve this.

Comment: Thanks will try and will get back to you soon once again thank you so much